# Simple Git Branch Switching Workflow

Tags: git

I am working on a project using Git. Now, I am working on a feature in a branch and ran across something that I need to see some code from someone else's branch to remind myself how a function he wrote works (these two branches will get merged when I am done).

I do not really want to commit my changes right now and git checkout his branch...then switch back over.

What is a better way to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tool for the job is [git-stash](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash). Running `git stash` in a Git directory with changed files will stash away your changes, bringing the working directory back to the state of `HEAD` (a *clean* state). This allows you to checkout a different branch, as well as many other operations. When you're done and back in this branch, run `git stash pop` to pop the changes in the stash back onto the working directory, bringing yourself back the state you were at before stashing the changes away.

```
$ git branch
* develop-back
  develop-other
$ git stash
$ git checkout develop-other
$ ...
$ git co develop-back
$ git stash pop
```

Yes, this works perfectly well and is very convenient. But remember that you shouldn't be afraid of committing changes in Git. In fact, git-stash does exactly that: commit your changes somewhere. Committing in Git means *saving your work*, and in this case that's exactly what you want to do. You can always reset-mixed:

```
$ git commit -am 'stashing away for a moment'
$ git co develop-other
$ ...
$ git co develop-back
$ git reset HEAD~
```

This workflow is equivalent to stashing, and you can see that it takes no more steps. git stash is just a "wrapper" around this procedure, with a somewhat more humane interface.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want to use [git stash](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash).

First execute `git stash`. Then checkout the other branch. Once you've finished taking a look, go back to your own branch, and use `git stash pop`.